# \label{} adds empty line

Tags: labels, empty-line

When I use the command `\label{}` before a section, it creates a blank line. How can I remove that empty line?

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \section{Test 1}
    \begin{align*}
        x
    \end{align*}\label{myLabel}%
    
    \section{Test 2}
    See page~\pageref{myLabel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: either put it inside the align, or add an empty line before the label command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\label` inside `align*` is ignored.

Comment: @cabohah ah right. So the empty line is needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I add an empty line before the label command, will the label command always be with the align* environment? In some situations, the label may fall on a page separate from the align* page, is that right?

Comment: yes, probably. You could try `\let\labelinalign\label` and then use `\labelinalign` inside the align* (but I didn't try with hyperref, that could change things).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It works with hyperref also.